# 13.04 - rsyslogd eating all the CPU it can

Tags: 13.04, cpu-load, vps, rsyslog, openvz

I'm on a VPS on ramnode.com, virtualized using OpenVZ, the installed OS was Ubuntu 12.10 but I ran `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade it to 13.04.

`rsyslogd` was consuming ~150% CPU, I really don't know much about Linux but I ran at someone's advice `` strace -c -p `pidof rsyslogd` `` on it, and here's the result:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   37.912236     9478059         4           select
  0.00    0.001000         500         2           write
  0.00    0.000000           0        14           gettimeofday
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           futex
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   37.913236                    24           total
```

So seemingly it's spending its time on that select syscall, but I don't know what that means :(

Running `` strace -p `pidof rsyslogd` `` gives only one line until I interrupt it:

```
select(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, {22, 56702}^C <unfinished ...>
```

What can be causing this? What can I do to fix it?

**Edit:** `tail /var/log/kern.log` gives me this:

```
Jun  7 21:42:26 camilo kernel: last message repeated 14010362 times
Jun  7 21:43:26 camilo kernel: last message repeated 13755525 times
Jun  7 21:44:26 camilo kernel: last message repeated 13745228 times
Jun  7 22:03:44 camilo kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jun  7 22:03:44 camilo kernel: Cannot read proc file system: 1 - Operation not permitted.
Jun  7 22:04:14 camilo kernel: last message repeated 6927277 times
Jun  7 22:05:14 camilo kernel: last message repeated 13931106 times
Jun  7 22:06:14 camilo kernel: last message repeated 13864233 times
Jun  7 22:09:46 camilo kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jun  7 22:09:46 camilo kernel: Cannot read proc file system: 1 - Operation not permitted.
```

That doesn't sound good :( The Kernel is `2.6.32-042stab076.8` and I don't think I can fiddle with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/523610.  The bug is fixed with recent distro kernels, but that doesn't help those of us running VMs where the host picks the kernel.  I don't have a fix, sorry.